# node-querybuilder returns error message despite providing data

Tags: node.js, node-modules, query-builder

I am using [node-querybuilder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-querybuilder#update_batch) to update data in batch.

This is what i am doing.

```
const key = 'tripId';
const where = {'tripId =' : id}

const dataset= 
[   { studentId: 43 }, 
    { studentId: 42 } 
];


db.queryBuilder.update_batch('trip_students_booking', dataset, key, where, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err);

});
```

In response i am getting this error message from `node-querybuilder`

> Error: update_batch(): You must provide some data to batch update!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would like to recommend you, avoid https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-querybuilder#update_batch as this library is not production ready and have bugs( I created pull request https://github.com/kylefarris/node-querybuilder/pull/24 ). You may like to have a look http://knexjs.org .

If you want to continue then you have to pass `Key` in object of `dataset`. In documentation,

> Name of the key in each data object that represents a where clause.

and index key required while where condition is optional, your code should be like

```
const key = 'tripId';

let dataset = [{
        tripId: id,
        studentId: 43
    },
    {
        tripId: id,
        studentId: 42
    }
];


db.queryBuilder.update_batch('trip_students_booking', dataset, key, (err, res) => {
    if (err && err.length > 0) return console.error(err);

});
```

If you want to try before merging and publishing new update of module, you can try to update line number 143 from `const results = null;` to `let results = null;` in file `./node_modules/node-querybuilder/drivers/mysql/query_builder.js`
I hope this will you

Comment: Thanks @Arif Khan, I want to execute this type of query. Can you please help me with this
`
Update trip_students_booking set status=1 where trip id =2 and studentId in (1,2,3)`